# What are the RGB values of the background color of tex.sx main site?

Tags: discussion, design

In his [contest entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35093), Gonzalo Medina claims that

```
% some colors that will be used (taken form the colors used at TeX.sx)
\definecolor{headtitle}{RGB}{167,63,63} %(red)
\definecolor{headbg}{RGB}{244,218,151} %(yellow)
\definecolor{grlngreen}{RGB}{208,212,171} %(green)
\definecolor{grlnblue}{RGB}{100,169,212} %(blue)
\    definecolor{grlngray}{RGB}{76,76,74} %(gray)
```

The only color that is even close to the main site background color(bgc) is the yellow above.  But, I think bgc is lighter than that.  What are the RGB numbers of bgc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main background color of the main site is the HTML color `FCFAF3` thats RGB `{252,250,243}`. You can see this with an HTML/CSS tool like Firebug quite easily.

The bar at the top is actually done using the following image:

[image]

The image seems to not have a single color but have some gradient.
It is also partially transparent.
Its channels are like follows:

```
  Channel statistics:
    Red:
      min: 210 (0.823529)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 247.107 (0.969047)
      standard deviation: 4.69842 (0.0184252)
      kurtosis: 2.0003
      skewness: -1.00234
    Green:
      min: 200 (0.784314)
      max: 250 (0.980392)
      mean: 236.447 (0.927243)
      standard deviation: 5.21225 (0.0204402)
      kurtosis: 1.47374
      skewness: -0.897676
    Blue:
      min: 143 (0.560784)
      max: 217 (0.85098)
      mean: 196.575 (0.770884)
      standard deviation: 8.48045 (0.0332567)
      kurtosis: 1.31946
      skewness: -0.934949
    Alpha:
      min: 135 (0.529412)
      max: 135 (0.529412)
      mean: 135 (0.529412)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 0
      skewness: 0
```